# MacBook Pro second display flickering between apps?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, screen

I read this answer which suggested using gfxCardStatus to force discrete only mode -- didn't help :( ([Flickering in Safari after switching back to integrated graphics](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73734/flickering-in-safari-after-switching-back-to-integrated-graphics))

What I am seeing is that applications on my Retina screen will flicker really bad when I have a second monitor attached via display port. Applications will flicker on top of each other, and it generally seems to affect the lower quarter of the screen, near the dock.

It's super annoying and often makes it impossible to read the bottom line of a full-screen terminal on my Retina monitor when there's a second monitor attached because it flickers so much.

Has anyone seen this?

OS X 10.9.2

2.6 GHz Retina 15" MacBook Pro, 16 GB RAM

EDIT: I find that it doesn't flicker when changing the display setting for the retina screen to "Best For Display" rather than "Scaled" -- but then everything on the retina screen is MASSIVE and "Fisher-Price" looking.

Comment: Could you take screenshots? Or aren't they blurry?
Do you have a official cable by Apple? (I like you saying *Fisher-Price looking* btw)

Comment: Yeah, I do have an official Apple cable...

Funny thing: I tried taking a video using Jing, but the area of the retina screen it allowed me to capture video of only extended to where the flickering began. Almost like the OS doesn't think the bottom of the screen should be addressable video area or something?